# Rename tag and remove attribute

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an XML document (generated by WiX heat) where I want to remove the root element name while removing the attribute. The source tree looks like this

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="HELP" />
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I figured out how to rename the node, but this doesn't remove the unnecessary attribute `xmlns`.

```
  <xsl:template match='/wix:Wix'>
    <Include>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </Include>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Even this template doesn't suppress the attribute xmlns -->
  <xsl:template match='@xmlns'/>
```

I event removed the `@*|` from the select clause. But this doesn't have any effect.

How can I produce with XSLT 1.0 the following desired output?

```
<Include>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="HELP" />
    </Fragment>
</Include>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this doesn't remove the unnecessary attribute `xmlns`.

`xmlns`is not an *attribute* - it's a *namespace*, a part of the node's name. If you don't want it in the output, you cannot copy the input nodes that are in a namespace - you must create new nodes instead, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/wix:Wix">
    <Include>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Include>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But I would like to know why. I did not found the `{}` in my XSLT books. What does happens there? I assume the `<xsl:copy-of select`=""/>` actually removes what is defined in the select pattern. But why does this use the attributes pattern `@*`? And why does this affect the tag with the namespace (not attribute) addition?

Comment: With regard to `{}` do a search for *attribute value template*. As for `xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`, your assumption is wrong - the instruction simply copies all attributes of the currently processed element. We are assuming here that none of your actual attributes is in a namespace, so these *can* be copied. Note that unlike elements, attributes do not inherit the namespace of their parent node.